# How far and how wide does Reinhard's Earthshatter reach?

Tags: overwatch

I play Reinhardt a lot, and I've noticed that when I bring my mighty hammer down, it doesn't reach nearly as far as I'd hope it would.

More often than not, a few enemies are either *just* out of reach of the area of effect, or just at the edge, even though I could swear they were within the area of the cracked-earth effect when my hammer came down.

I've also noticed, very rarely, that some enemies will be affected by Earthshatter, even though they should technically be in the air and therefore avoiding the effect.

So what are the *real* dimensions of the area of effect for Earthshatter?  And are there any less-than-obvious actions that prevent it from taking effect?

Comment: Well hell, there are times when I'm out of the range of the ground-pound animation, but I still get knocked down, so I'd like to know to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EarthShatter reaches 20m forward.**

As far as I can tell for width, its as wide as the normal field of view but I cant find any specific numbers as it's a cone.

You can play with this yourself, by jumping into the training grounds, where the friendly robot is shooting, the ground has markings every 5 meters.

20 metres is the distance between both turrets (the friendly and the enemy) [at the 69th second of this video](https://youtu.be/sFMgC2DB1sU?t=69)

Comment: Do you know how high up this affects? There are times when I'm standing on the payload, and I still get knocked down.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'd assume it doesn't go up as a simple jump is enough to avoid the ult. More likely the hammer actually hit the payload and spread on to it a swell.

Comment: Do you have an in-game reference for how far this is?  I know a meter is a meter, but something to visualize would be helpful.

Comment: @ИвоНедев In my experience, jumping (or even hovering close to the floor as Pharah) is not enough to escape the knockdown, which makes sense considering how important jumping is when dodging gunfire. Also, though most walls (including another Reinhardt's shield) stop Earthshatter, it seems to affect anything on or behind the payload, possibly due to the fact that the payload itself hovers.

Comment: @Zibbobz Check edit

Comment: @ИвоНедев That's very helpful - an image capture with an outlined area of effect would be better, but that's above and beyond what's necessary.